# How to identify a class and an interface in the Java code?

Tags: java

Say suppose I have the following Java code.

```
    public class Example {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Person person = new Employee();
        }
    }
```

How to find out whether the Person is a class or an interface?

Because the `Employee` class can extend it if it's a class, or implement it if it's an interface.

And in both cases **Person person = new Employee();** is valid.

Comment: why do you need it at runtime?

Comment: I would just `Ctrl+Click` the `Person` in my IDE :) Further, I understand the question, but I really don't see any value of knowing the answer... What would you like to do with this information?

Comment: Knowing whether it is a Class or Interface is useless you mean to say.

Comment: @Bozho, I have Classes which is written by somebody else, and i am going through them, so when this type of code is written, i am getting confused whether the declared type is a Class or Interface.

Comment: During runtime, yes. During writing code, just check source/javadoc (but that would have been a too obvious answer so I was unsure if you *actually* asked that, anyway, I posted an answer).

Comment: Your IDE tells you that - with different icons, with compile time errors, etc. No need to check it at runtime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't already know whether `Person` is an interface or a class by nature of the documentation for the class/interface itself (you're using it, presumably you have some docs or something?), you can tell with code:

```
if (Person.class.isInterface()) {
   // It's an interface
}
```

Details [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInterface()).

**Edit**: Based on your comment, here's an off-the-cuff utility you can use:

```
public class CheckThingy
{
    public static final void main(String[] params)
    {
        String name;
        Class  c;

        if (params.length < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Please give a class/interface name");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        name = params[0];
        try
        {
            c = Class.forName(name);
            System.out.println(name + " is " + (c.isInterface() ? "an interface." : "a class."));
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(name + " not found in the classpath.");
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
java CheckThingy Person
```

Comment: Thanks Crowder. But i have Classes which is written by somebody else, and i am going through them, so when this type of code is written, i am getting confused whether the declared type is a Class or Interface.

Comment: Sorry about that. Brain fart. Removed the downvote and comment as soon as I realised.

Comment: @gurukulki: Fair 'nuff, you can use the above to create a utility to figure it out. You can't tell just by looking.

Comment: @Tom: As I said, brain fart. Joachim Sauer kindly fixed that in my post before I twigged on.

Answer (score 5):

I think that in this case, you don't know because you *shouldn't* know. If you're writing something that extends or implements (the Employee class), then it's up to you to go look at the docs or the source code.

If, as in your example, you're just utilizing some classes/interfaces, you shouldn't need know or care if the Person class is concrete or abstract, or an interface, as long as it has a well defined API.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `isInterface()` method of the `Class` class to do this. What is your reason for doing this though? Do you have a poorly documented library where you need to figure this out? Perhaps if we knew what you were trying to do, a more elegant solution could be offered.

```
if(Class.forName("Person").isInterface())
    //do interface stuff
else
    //do class stuff
```

or

```
if(Person.class.isInterface())
    ...
```

EDIT: On reading your comment to T.J. Crowder's answer. This is what I would do:

```
if(Person.class.isInterface())
    System.out.println("Person is an Interface");
else
    System.out.println("Person is a class");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+leftclick on `Person` in your IDE and/or read its source and/or the javadoc.

If you aren't using an IDE yet, I can recommend [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) or [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html). If you're doing Java EE (JSP/Servlet and that kind of stuff), either grab Eclipse for Java **EE** or pay for [IDEA Ultimate edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).